# PHP, Inserting Form Data Into MYSQLi

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, mysqli

I am having trouble creating this login system. When someone logs in I want it to create a table, if not already. Then bring them to the form page, then insert the data. I have everything working until the insert on the last page.

After Steam API Login

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require ('../../../mysql_connect/mysqli_connect_accounts.php');
    require ('../steamauth/steamauth.php');
    require ('../steamauth/userInfo.php');
    $steamid=$_SESSION['steamid'];
    
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `".$steamid."`";
    
    $response = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
    
if($response){
        header("Location: http://theskindealer.com/index.php");
    } else {    
        $create = "CREATE TABLE `".$steamid."` (
        steam64 VARCHAR(30), 
        fullname VARCHAR(60),
        tradeurl VARCHAR(60),
        email VARCHAR(50),
        age INT(3),
        tos INT(1),
        access INT(1),
        freeze INT(1),
        balance DECIMAL(9,2),
        newsletter INT(1),
        emailVerified INT(1)
        )";
        if ($dbc->query($create) === TRUE) {
        
            header("Location: http://theskindealer.com/scripts/createAccount.php");

        } else {
            header("Location: http://theskindealer.com/pages/errorlogin.php");
        }
}
$stmt->close();
$dbc->close();
    
?>
```

Then it REDIRECTS to the form page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<?php
session_start();
require ('../../../mysql_connect/mysqli_connect_accounts.php');
require ('../steamauth/steamauth.php');
require ('../steamauth/userInfo.php');
$steamid=$_SESSION['steamid'];
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>TheSkinDealer | Setup</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/accept.css"></head><body>
<div id="content">
<div id="acceptbox">
<img src="../images/logo.png">
<form action="setup.php" method="post">
        
<div id="name1">Full Name:</br> <input type="text" name="fullname"> </br></div>
<div id="name1">TradeURL: <a target="_blank" href="http://steamcommunity.com/id/me/tradeoffers/privacy#trade_offer_access_url">(?)</a></div> <input type="text" name="tradeurl"> </br>
<div id="name1">EMAIL:</div> <input type="text" name="email"> </br>
<div id="checkboxes">
<a href="http://theskindealer.com/tos/tos.php" target="_blank">Terms Of Serice</a>:  <input type="checkbox" name="tos" value="1"> </br>
18 Or Older:  <input type="checkbox" name="age" value="1"></br>
Newsletter:  <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" value="1"></br>
</div>
<div id="returnhome">
<div id="accept"><input type="submit" value="Create Account"></a></div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
<center><div id="par">Purchases Or Sales Cannot Be Made Without Accepting TOS.</div></center>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Lastly the insert page:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require ('../../../mysql_connect/mysqli_connect_accounts.php');
    require ('../steamauth/steamauth.php');
    require ('../steamauth/userInfo.php');
    $steamid=$_SESSION['steamid'];
        
            $insert = "INSERT INTO `".$steamid."` (steam64, freeze, access, 
tos, balance, age, email, tradeurl, fullname, newsletter, emailVerified) 
                       VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
            $stmt = $dbc->prepare($insert);
            $stmt->bind_param('sssssssssss', 
                $steam64, 
                $freeze, 
                $access, 
                $tos, 
                $balance, 
                $age, 
                $email, 
                $tradeurl, 
                $fullname,
                $newsletter,
                $emailVerified
            );
            
            $steam64 = $steamid;
            $freeze = 0;
            $access = 0;
            $tos = $_POST["tos"];
            $balance = 0.00;
            $age = $_POST["age"];
            $email = $_POST["email"];
            $tradeurl = $_POST["tradeurl"];
            $fullname = $_POST["fullname"];
            $newsletter = $_POST["newsletter"];
            $emailVerified = 0;
            $stmt->execute();
        
            header("Location: http://theskindealer.com/");
$stmt->close();
$dbc->close();
    
?>
```

Comment: Are you getting errors? You should set up error reporting on your insert and post error statement.

Comment: Are you creating a new database table for each user on this system? Does that seem scalable?

Comment: Consider using `VARCHAR(255)` as a default general-purpose string-type field and only override this if you have a compelling reason. Many MySQL installations will silently truncate any data which doesn’t fit, resulting in lost data, user complaints, and other serious issues. Names and email addresses are quite frequently surprisingly long, so accommodating these is important.

Comment: **WARNING**: Using the error-suppressing YOLO operator (`@`) obscures problems with your code and makes debugging issues like this a whole lot more complicated. That's a tool of last resort and should only be used in exceptional circumstances. You should display an error message for the user, log a problem, initiate some kind of retry, or all of these things in conjunction.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Creating a table per user really goes against the grain when it comes to relational database design. You should have one table per "entity" and key that with columns like `user_id` where necessary to separate the data along different relational parameters. If you create all these tables there's no easy way to query them all at once, from a relational perspective your data is scattered all over the place. If you ever need to make a schema change to add a new column you've got a lot of work to do.

Comment: This question is really not answerable. Try dividing your problem in smaller pieces. And PLEASE don't create tables dynamically, that's recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get any errors when executing this script?
You could for instance add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of your script to get a better look at errors.

Looking at the script it seems like you are binding variables before they exist.
You should put the variable assigments before the `bind_param` exetution:

```
    $steam64 = $steamid;
    $freeze = 0;
    $access = 0;
    $tos = $_POST["tos"];
    $balance = 0.00;
    $age = $_POST["age"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $tradeurl = $_POST["tradeurl"];
    $fullname = $_POST["fullname"];
    $newsletter = $_POST["newsletter"];
    $emailVerified = 0;



   $stmt->bind_param('sssssssssss', 
        $steam64, 
        $freeze, 
        $access, 
        $tos, 
        $balance, 
        $age, 
        $email, 
        $tradeurl, 
        $fullname,
        $newsletter,
        $emailVerified
    );

    $stmt->execute();
```

Also keep in mind that numeric values like 0 must be bind with 'i' instead of 's'
See http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php for more info.

For instance.

```
   $stmt->bind_param('iiisdissssi',
```